# routing error when reading from tmp dir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, carrierwave

I'm using carrierWave to upload covers in tmp dir, but when got an routting error when try to access them, tried to use Rack::static to listen for the requests but didn't solve it,

*NOTE I can't make an action and use send_file for it as it didn't work on heroku!

```
#config.ru
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
use Rack::Static, :urls => ["/uploads"], :root => "tmp"
run Aa::Application

#CarrierWave.rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
 config.root = Rails.root.join('tmp') # adding these...
 config.cache_dir = 'uploads' # ...two lines
end

#cover_uploader.rb
class CoverUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  end

  def cache_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  end

end
```